# 10 unique random number between 1 - 10 javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do i generate 1 - 10 unique numbers, I did this

```
function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
    var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min);
    return number;
}
```

but this sometime return duplicate numbers
i want all the number to go around once before they apear again

Comment: The 10 unique integers between 1 and 10 are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: Then you want to _shuffle_ an array of the numbers from 1 through 10, not generate random numbers from 1 through 10.

Comment: Yeah but i want them in different order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
function shuffle(arra1) {
    var ctr = arra1.length, temp, index;

    while (ctr > 0) {

        index = Math.floor(Math.random() * ctr);
        ctr--;
        temp = arra1[ctr];
        arra1[ctr] = arra1[index];
        arra1[index] = temp;
    }
    return arra1;
}
var myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,10];
console.log(shuffle(myArray));
```